Since Fedora 41, how do you list all the dnf configuration values?
Since Fedora 41, the following command does not work anymore:
$ sudo dnf config-manager --dump
Unknown argument "dump" for command "config-manager".

The list of Changes between DNF and DNF5 does not mention this change.
Using dnf, how do you list all the dnf configuration values?

Not a Fedora user, but man dnf?

@ChrisDavies Do you mean I got to reread thousand of man pages each time the fedora team choose to redesign dnf?

Of course not. Why would you need to read any more than the one man page for the affected command?

The new --dump-main-config option seems to provide the same functionality in dnf5:
$ sudo dnf --dump-main-config
======== Main configuration: ========
allow_downgrade = 1
allow_vendor_change = 1
assumeno = 0
assumeyes = 0
...
zchunk = 1

